# OnButtonCLick tag is not firing?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have defined a trigger having event name as "gtmEvent" and a tag "AccountCreated". When I click on a button ("createAccount") it goes to next page. But tag is not fired and also in summary the event is not listed but when i check google analytics through console i found that tag is there in event name.

Is it when you click on page and after clicking you stayed at same page only then the event listed on summary otherwise it will lost. ??

Comment: Try to do a Ctrl+click to force the button action to open in another window. If you have Dev console open then you should be able to see the event in the network tab. Make sure you preserve log as well. Check also the datalayer.

Comment: Thanks.. ctrl+click is not working in ubuntu. But When i check my network i found this event was there.

Comment: Check also in real time reports. If you see the event there then you are probably just missing the event due to what you've described.

Comment: I am using google tag manager not google analytics directly. How can i check the real time report??

Comment: You can check in the real time reports when you go into Google Analytics. On the left column there is a section called Real Time. From there you can check the Events section. This report is applicable to both GA and GTM.